# Ox-epub Window required for cover

Tags: org-mode, org-export, batch-mode

When exporting in batch mode (for example in continuous integration) with `ox-epub`:

```sh
emacs --batch main.org --eval="(package-initialize)" --eval="(require 'ox-epub)" --funcal org-epub-export-to-epub --kill
```

if the keyword  `EPUBCOVER` is set, the following error arises:

```
ox-epub eport error: (error Window system frame should be used)
```

Without the `--batch` argument the final file is correctly generated, but in some contexts (for example in docker on Gitlab CI) it is not possible to start Emacs with a GUI and the batch mode is the only available way.
Even with `--no-x-resources` instead of `--batch` there is the same problem.

Is there a way to allow exporting an ePub with a cover in batch mode?

Comment: `--batch` does not load the user-specific init file (i.e. it implicitly does `-q`). Does adding `-l ~/.emacs.d/init.el` to the command line resolve the problem? If so, you might want to pare it down to a minimal file that contains the bare essentials required to resolve it and then load that. You might also include the code for the two `--eval` options in that minimal file, so you can just do `-l /path/to/minimal.el` file and the funcall (or even include the funcall in the file).

Comment: The above will probably not work:that error is generated by C code in frame.c and checks that emacs is running under a window system. You probably will need to `edebug` the macro `org-epub--export-wrapper` and step through it to pinpoint who exactly ends up needing the window system. There's about a dozen places in C code that call the check function `check_window_system()`, and there are probably hundreds of places in lisp code that end up calling it, so it's probably better to go top-down than botttom-up.

Comment: Yes indeed I use an elisp file, here I have put in this way to give a minimum example.
I tried now with `-l ~/.emacs.d/init.el` and the error is the same. It seems to me its because some component of the function to include the cover requires the GUI, but I think that if this is true is a sort of bug: it cannot be required the GUI to put a png into an epub.

Comment: You might want to open an issue on the ox-epub github site  http://github.com/ofosos/org-epub

Comment: Yes I have already done: https://github.com/ofosos/ox-epub/issues/33  
But in the meanwile I asked here to see if someone else has got the same problem.  Now I will try with edebug (I may take a while because I never used it)